# Making a program auto login to twitch.tv

Tags: bots, autologin, twitch

So im trying to make a program with multiple buttons. Basically each button will relate to one account on twitch(.)tv . I help doing this. I understand the button needs to 1. navigate to twitch(.)tv/login . 2. then it needs to get the elementbyID of the login id for that text box. Can someone please help with this error I am getting?  http://prntscr.com/3aqhwq 
Could someone also make sure that I have the right ID for that login blank on twitch(.)tv/login . I need to be able to make it to automatically input a email into the email text box of that webpage and then the password then to click to submit button, Like invokemember. http://prntscr.com/3aqieh

Answer (score 0):

The problem with with your code is You place navigate and get element-id in on same button
loading page takes some time but your code is not waiting for that time .
place `navigate url` to other button or wait till `browser load complete`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_user_login").SetAttribute("Value", "123@gmail.com")
    End Sub
```